# Can't read property of undefined, but it's clearly not undefined

Tags: templates, pug

This code

```
div
    each dum in dummy
        div !{JSON.stringify(dum)}
```

outputs, as seen below, an object `{"prop":3}` So obviously, `prop` should be accessible via

```
        div !{dum.prop}
        div !{dum['prop']}
```

but it suddenly becomes undefined.

[image]

The `dummy` is passed by node

```
var dummy = [];
dummy[10] = {prop:3};

res.render('dummy.jade', {
    dummy: dummy
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

PS: Converting the object to Javascript even works

[image]

Comment: I don't know what's wrong, but it's saying that "dum" is undefined, and not its property.

Comment: @Jason But "dum" ***is*** defined. It is {"prop":3} as seen.. no?

Comment: I agree with your assessment, but the error says it cannot read the property of `undefined` which would indicate that dum is undefined. But it prints out so that doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the problem is that **sparse array**s don't work with Jade.

So

```
dummy[10] = {prop:3};
```

doesn't work but

```
dummy[0] = {prop:3};
```

does.

---

https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/1445